# How to add multiple icon for same position in React-leaflet version 3

Tags: typescript, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I'm developing an app using React-leaflet version 3 with TypeScript. In my app, I have the requirement to add multiple icons for  one position. EX: A particular [lat,long] position identified as having a blood donation camp, an outdoor checkup center at the morning 8 A.M. And at the afternoon 3 P.M the same location would have a makeshift music concert and a free-food center. So, at a time I need to place atleast two icons for my marker. Ex: for the morning the icon for blood donation camp and outdoor checkup. In the marker tag the icon attribute allows to have only one value.

So, I tried this option. However no luck so far.

I used `L.divIcon`

```
const mapNodeIcon = L.divIcon({
html: `<div class="multi-icon-div">
<img src="../icon/myIcons/bloodDonCamp.svg" width="30px"/>
<img src="../icon/myIcons/outdoorCheck.svg" width="30px"/>  
</div>`,
iconAnchor: [10, 10],
popupAnchor: [0, -19],
iconSize: [55, 55],
});
```

> Marker Tag

```
<Marker 
        key={myMap.id} 
        position={[lat, lng]}
        icon={mapNodeIcon}
        >
        <Popup>
          <h3>This is the event location</h3>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
```

This problem here I'm facing is,the svg icon images are not loading in the div though the iconDiv is visible as a marker on the map. How to approach this issue?

May be, it's a simple question but even it can be solved this way, is this a good approach ? Is there any other possible efficient approach ? As, my map will render different svg icons depending on time(morning and afternoon) I have doubts that if this is a faster approach for a multinode map.

Any idea and help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Use this [react-leaflet-markercluster](https://github.com/YUzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster#readme) library

Comment: hello @GrzegorzT. THanks for your answer. I saw this plugins. but This plugin actually put an aggregated icon for all the icons. So, on the map you would see this final aggregated icon and when you click it, you would see other icons. This I don't want. I want all my icons are always visible in a specific [lat,lng] for the respective marker.

Answer (score 1):

Importing svg the way you did it won't work. Below you have the correct svg import.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {ReactComponent as Logo} from './logo.svg';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Logo />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

At this [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/) you have a whole list of ways to add svg

**-- Update--**

```js
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import tileLayer from '../util/tileLayer';
import L from 'leaflet';

import facebook from './facebook-square.svg';
import twitter from './twitter.svg';

const center = [52.22977, 21.01178];

const MapWrapper = () => {

  const mapNodeIcon = L.divIcon({
    html: `<div style="display: flex;">
      <img src="${facebook}" width="30px"/>
      <img src="${twitter}" width="30px"/>  
    </div>`,
    iconAnchor: [10, 10],
    popupAnchor: [0, -19],
    iconSize: [55, 55],
  });

  return (
    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={18} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer {...tileLayer} />

      <Marker position={center} icon={mapNodeIcon}>
        <Popup>Center Warsaw</Popup>
      </Marker>

    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default MapWrapper;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time however it doesn't work on leaflet marker tag. Marker tag allows to pass icon or divIcon . So, even if I try to pass an children react component to the marker tag it doesn't work.

Comment: I made an update of the example and it works as it should. You can easily add two icons to `divIcon`.